# Displaying data from sqlite database in Flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

I am currently working on my first Flutter-App and I have the following problem: I can't display any data from the sqlite db on the screen. The data is stored in the database - I can print it in the console, but I don't manage to display it on the screen.
In the tutorials I watched, they always used the ListView.builder. However I only want to display one specific name from a certain id - and not the whole db content.

- Are there other ways to display data from the sqlite database in flutter then ListView?
- Can I use ListView to only show a specific dataset (where id =...)? If so, could you give me an example? Everything I've tried didn't work.
- Can you recommend any good tutorials/ articels on this matter?

I'm grateful for every advice you might have concerning this problem!

Comment: Without actual code, no one can guide you. But if you want a basic understanding of how sqflite works check https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite and this article on medium https://medium.com/flutter-community/using-sqlite-in-flutter-187c1a82e8b

Answer (score 0):

Use FutureBuilder and in future, pass the functions to fetch specific row from dao, the results will be observed on snapshot where you can display the data.

Here is the example I've done, Hope it would helps you

```
body: StreamBuilder<ChatHistorie>(
          stream: model.getHistory(_historyId),
          builder: (context, snapShot) {
            if (snapShot.hasData && snapShot.data!= null)
               return Text(data.message);
            else
                return Center(child: Text("No data found"));
          },
        ),
```